# Moving a sprite to click over time in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to have code where I can click a sprite, click a position and it will move there over a period of time.

Here is my code:

```
def update(self, mousePosX, mousePosY, mouseDown):
    #Walk
    self.walkCool += 1

    self.rect.x += self.xIncrement
    self.rect.y += self.yIncrement

    if self.rect.x == self.targetX:
            self.yIncrement = 0
            self.xIncrement = 0

    if self.selected == True:

        pg.draw.line(screen, (18, 219, 255), (self.rect.x + self.size//2, self.rect.y + self.size//2) , (mousePosX, mousePosY), 3)


        if mouseDown[0] and self.walkCool > 20:  

            self.targetX = mousePosX
            self.targetY = mousePosY
            self.dy = self.targetY - self.rect.y
            self.dx = self.targetX - self.rect.x
            print(self.dx,self.dy)

            self.yIncrement = self.dy/self.dx
            if self.dy > 0 and self.dx < 0:
                self.yIncrement = self.yIncrement * -1
            if self.dx < 0:
                self.xIncrement = -1
            elif self.dx > 0:
                self.xIncrement = 1
            else:
                self.xIncrement = 0
```

The above code is for the update function in my sprite class (which is called every time round my update loop). My issues are that if I get a dx/dy < 1 then it doesn't seem to travel to the exact click position, and I also can't get it to move to the (-, +) quadrant. Not sure how to solve these issues.

Answer (score 0):

First use [vectors](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) to make your life easier. Set the sprite's goal when the user clicks a mouse button. Calculate the vector to the goal (called `heading` here), normalize and scale it to the desired speed, then use it as the velocity vector. When the sprite is approaching the goal you need to slow it down, otherwise it would move quickly back and forth.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 50))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('dodgerblue1'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel = Vector2(0, 0)
        # Store the actual position as another vector because
        # rect coordinates can only be integers.
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)
        self.max_speed = 5
        self.goal = Vector2(pos)
        self.goal_radius = 40

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel  # Update the position vector first.
        self.rect.center = self.pos  # Update the rect afterwards.

        # This vector points to the goal.
        heading = self.goal - self.pos
        distance = heading.length()
        # Normalize it, so that we can scale it to the desired length/speed below.
        if heading:  # Can't normalize a zero vector.
            heading.normalize_ip()

        if distance > self.goal_radius:
            # Move with maximum speed.
            self.vel = heading * self.max_speed
        else:
            # Slow down when we're approaching the goal.
            self.vel = heading * (distance/self.goal_radius * self.max_speed)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    player = Player((100, 300), all_sprites)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # Set the goal of the player.
                player.goal = Vector2(event.pos)

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: Here are [some videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1jo_qsO5c4&list=PLsk-HSGFjnaHYvbjMbTQG6kLhhZHLzdb3&index=4) about steering behaviors.